# SpringBoot WebClient Request with Identifier and Secret or Hashed Password

Tags: java, php, spring-boot, curl, spring-webclient

I am having a `curl php` request that looks like this below

```
$curlInit = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.myurl.com/');
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    http_build_query(
        array(
            'action' => 'GetSearchDetails',
            'username' => 'lambistic',
            'password' => 'lambistic######',
            'responsetype' => 'json',
        )
    )
);
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($curlInit);
curl_close($curlInit);
```

What i am trying to achieve is to do the same with `web client` in springboot java and below is how i am trying to do it with web client

```
public Mono<SearchDetailsResponse> sendSearchDetailsRequest() {

        return webClient.post()
                .uri("https://www.myurl.com/")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                    httpHeaders.set("username", "lambistic");
                    httpHeaders.set("password", "lambistic######");
                })
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(SearchDetailsResponse.class);
}
```

I am not getting any response what might i be doing wrong with the web client

Answer (score 0):

http_build_query add parameters as query string.
In your webclient, you add them as headers. I guess you have to change this:

```
webClient
.post()
.uri("https://www.myurl.com?action=GetSearchDetails&username=lambistic&password=lambistic#####&responsetype=json")
.retrieve()
.bodyToMono(SearchDetailsResponse.class);
```

Comment: is the a space after `actions= ` ?

Comment: Typo. No space. Also action, not actions.

Comment: @grekier its working well in postman but now i am getting  `403 Forbidden from POST https://www.myurl.com?action=GetSearchDetails&username=lambistic&password=lambistic#####&responsetype=json` is there some set up that i am missing in the webClient

Comment: Impossible to say without looking at the server code. Usually 403 means that login went through OK but you do not have the required permission. It might be some IP blocking, missing extra headers or parameters, a typo in the URL, etc...